# Remote Desktop: Works on one computer but not another

Tags: remote-desktop

(also posted on stackoverflow and server fault)

Finally switching from desktop to laptop at work.  I use Remote Desktop quite a bit to access our server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard).  I can access the server from the desktop (32 bit, Windows 7 Enterprise), but when I try from the new laptop (64 bit, Window 7 Enterprise), I go thru the login screen then I get the "Configuring remote session.." forever and the display never pops up.  I'm admin everywhere, so that's not the issue.

Did a little research, but nothing I've read seems to relate to my situation.  I have tried:

- renaming the mstsc in \windows\system32 to .OLD and running the 32-bit mstsc from \windows\SysWOW64.  No joy.
- Connecting FROM the server to the laptop.  Works fine.
- Created a batch file:

  ```
  @echo off
  set WinDir=
  start C:WindowsSysWow64mstsc.exe
  ```

  No joy.

Anybody else have this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's future reference, the problem was with the audio driver.  Deleted the RealTek driver that had been installed and used the generic windows driver, and was able to remote desktop again.